# Copy Option in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

is it possible to enable copy command on a textbox which is having IsEnabled property set to false in wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the 'IsReadOnly' property to true, copy command would be enabled and textbox uneditable.

Comment: can't do that currently due to some reason.

Comment: The proper property name is "IsReadOnly"

Answer (score -1):

add a context menu to the form which will be displayed only if right-clicked on the disabled textbox. the context menu will have only one option, copy. in its event handler, copy the textbox content to the clipboard.

Comment: in WPF , if control is disabled than context menu will not work.

Comment: on the other hand, you can also make the textbox read-only and make the cursor an ordinary pointer for that textbox. 

There is some way around, a stupid but working trick.